# Can't auto login to Gmail using selenium webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, gmail, autologin

public class AutoEmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {[image]

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\try\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AutoEmail\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 

    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?");

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"))).sendKeys("email@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"))).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
}
```

}

Comment: If you gonna often run the script, google might stop sign in due to security concern. Have you successfully run your code once as i can not see any mistakes in code ? @Ace.

Answer (score 3):

A quote from [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en):

To help protect your account, Google doesn’t let you sign in from some browsers. Google might stop sign-ins from browsers that:

1. Don’t support JavaScript or have Javascript turned off.
2. Have unsecure or unsupported extensions added.
3. **Use automation testing frameworks.**
4. Are embedded in a different application.